# Problem with windows in Ubuntu MATE

Tags: radeon, gpu, ubuntu-mate

Please have a look at [this gif](https://gfycat.com/PlayfulCompassionateDegus). Is this a GPU problem as currently, I had to turn off my card (AMD Radeon HD 7670M) because of the "Ring 0 Test failure."

Comment: Have you updated your system?

Comment: @George , I clean installed Ubuntu MATE 16.04 yesterday, previously it was the regular Unity version. I did not face this problem there.

Comment: When you click on that icon what does it say?

Comment: @George If you are talking about that red icon, that was the Screen Recorder, I was only trying to resume the minimised windows. After this problem happens, if I click anywhere on the desktop or press a key, it goes away.